# How do I get my Django context variables into my JS file?

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm trying to get data from a Django Backend to display on a map with Google Maps API, but I can't figure out how to pass the variables into the Javascript. Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Django Method:

```
def home(request):
    //stuff that processes the method
    return render(request, 'map/index.html', {'lats': lats, "longs": longs, 'lat': lat, 'long': long, 'names': names, 'scores': scores})
```

HTML Snippet:

```
 <script> src = getlocation.js></script>
    <!-- this implements the navbar-->
    <div id="navbar"></div>
    <script type = "module" src = ../../static/navbar.js></script>
    <!-- input tag-->


    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input id="address" type="text" name="address">
        <input type="submit" style="display: none" />

    </form>

    <script>
        var names = {{ names }};
        var lats = {{ lats }};
        var longs = {{ longs }};
        var scores = {{ scores }};
        var lat = {{ lat }};
        var long = {{ long }};
    </script>

    <!-- this implements the map-->
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src = ../../static/index.js> </script>
```

Javascript Snippet(index.js):

```
let locations = new Array(names.length);
for(let count = 0; count < names.length; count++){
    locations[count] = [names[count], lats[count], longs[count], scores[count]];
}
let curlat = lat, curlong = long;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply save the variable to `window` in your template:

```
<script>
    window.names = {{ names }};
    window.lats = {{ lats }};
    window.longs = {{ longs }};
    window.scores = {{ scores }};
    window.lat = {{ lat }};
    window.long = {{ long }};
</script>
```

Now in your js file:

```
let locations = new Array(names.length);
for(let count = 0; count < names.length; count++){
    locations[count] = [window.names[count], window.lats[count], window.longs[count], window.scores[count]];
}
let curlat = lat, curlong = long;
```